# How do I reverse a triangle strip with EVEN number of vertices?

Tags: opengl, 3d, directx

I know to reverse the orientation of a triangle strip with an ODD number of vertices I can reverse the vertices; ABCDE becomes EDCBA.

However, this does NOT seem to work with a triangle strip with an EVEN number of vertices.

I have tried a number of techniques I have read about online, however, none of them seem to work.

I have tried converting ABCDEF to BADCFE, however, I wind up with strange glitches in the mesh when it renders.

I have also read that just flipping B and C should work, but the rendering still does not flip the orientation of subsequent triangles.

Is it possible to reverse the orientation of a triangle strip with an EVEN number of vertices by changing the indexes of the strip only?

I only have access to the binary index list for the vertices at this time, so I can not add degenerate triangles, or otherwise change the number of indices in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the winding order of a triangle strip of arbitrary length. You can only change the winding order of a strip of odd length. Not without changing the strip itself.

Consider this strip:

[image: Triangle strip]

If you switch the order of the middle pairs of vertices (my original algorithm, which I deleted), the triangles you get (using the current numbers) are:

(0, 2, 1), (2, 1, 4), (1, 4, 3), ...

Notice the second triangle: 2, 1, 4. It's a *completely different triangle*; it's not one that's actually in this strip. Neither is 1, 4, 3.

This *appears* to work, because it covers the same *area*. But it doesn't actually work, because it's drawing a different set of triangles. Values will be interpolated in different ways, and the result will be wrong. Maybe not *noticeably* wrong, but wrong nevertheless.

There is no algorithm that can take an arbitrary triangle strip and reverse its winding order. By their nature, triangle strips are bound by their winding order, and you can't just reverse it in all cases.

That's why APIs have ways to simply reverse the expected winding order. You mentioned:

> My project involves hacking the course files for Mario Kart Wii

Why not just take their triangle strips, using their winding, and turn them into a triangle *list* instead of drawing a strip. That way, you can change the winding in the data much more easily.

Comment: Nicol, thank you for your input. I have found other resources that say to repeat the first vertex of an even tristrip to introduce a degenerate triangle, which then reverses the remaining triangles in the strip. The problem with turning them into triangle lists is that, for now, I am unable to change the size of the file. However, I am now going to see if it is possible to do so I can get this working. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @Eidola: you don't have to change the file. Do it as part of the loading process.

Comment: I am hacking the file, which is then loaded by the Wii. I have no control over the loading process, only the binary file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Add a degenerate triangle to the strip and then reverse it.

Comment: I have long since stopped working on this project, was surprised to see another post here.

While your answer is correct, it was not that simple as I was dealing with binary blobs, so there was nowhere to stick the degenerate triangle.

I wound up having to load the track file, parse the file, create the new triangle strip and rewrite a new file... which worked. :)